# unable to create_all() from psql -> sqlite3 in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to dump PostgressSQL -> to -> SQLite3 with all its data.

The main idea, was to create two engines, one for PSQL and second for sqlite3. then I `reflect` the psql engine on the sqlite engine - and run `create_all()` but then I receive the following error

```
2019-07-18 11:41:47,660 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-07-18 11:41:47,660 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ... etc ...
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pysqlite2.dbapi2.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error [SQL: u"\nCREATE TABLE table1 (\n\tcolumn_id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('table1_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL, \n\t
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Which is funny, because SQLAlchemy generated that `CREATE TABLE` - did. and the issue is when it's going to execute that `create table` in `sqlite3` then `sqlite3` throw the error back to SQLAlchemy - where it doesn't understand what are the following `nextval` and `::` are:

```
column_id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('table1_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
column_name VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'no-name'::character varying,
```

Personally I don't even need those - as the sqlite will be used as a snapshot DB, but how can I ignore that ? or adjust that ?

## EDIT 1- with a specific model

If inside the code I write something like this

```
class Table1(Base):
    __table__ = Table('table1',
                    Base.metadata,
                    Column('column_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                    Column('column_name', Text, default='no-name'),
                    autoload=True)
```

Working example - but I'm trying to do the same w/o `class Table1`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


def review_md_tables(metadata):

    if not metadata.sorted_tables:
        print "-> Tables not found"
        return

    for Table in metadata.sorted_tables:
        print "->", Table.name


print "PSQL database"
psql_url = "postgress://..."
psql_engine = create_engine(psql_url, echo=False)
psql_base = declarative_base(bind=psql_engine)
review_md_tables(psql_base.metadata)

class Table1(psql_base):
    __table__ = Table('table1',
                    pql_base.metadata,
                    Column('column_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                    Column('column_name', Text, default='no-name'),
                    autoload=True)

review_md_tables(psql_base.metadata)

sqlite_url = "sqlite:////tmp/db.sqlite"
sqlite_enging = create_engine(sqlite_url, echo=False)

# Duplicate PSQL tables -> SQLite
psql_base.metadata.create_all(sqlite_enging)
```

Issue is, I don't want to start writing class Models for every table in the DB ... any thoughts ?

Comment: I have an other idea for you: to move data from one database to an other use a standard data format like CSV. Export the contents of your tables from postgres to CSV files and import them in sqlite. See this: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/export-postgresql-table-to-csv-file/ and this: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/

Comment: thanks, I'm aware but I don't want to go that path ...

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has a better idea, this is the solution I found so far - is to remove the `server_default` from those columns one by one ( we can define with `default` an SQLAlchemy default ..

```
def remove_defaults_from_tables(metadata):
    for Table in metadata.sorted_tables:
        print "--> Adjusting table: ", Table.name

        # Fixing PSQL unsupported DEFAULT & serial columns
        # https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/525
        # https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/1565
        if Table.name in ["table1", "table2"]:
            Table.c.id.server_default = None
```

So this function should be used after filling all the `metadata` with `Tables`

```
# This doesn't require pre-defined Models - 
# BUT they will also load those special PSQL variables which SQLAlchemy 
# can't determine later during the `create_all`
Base.metadata.reflect(bind=my_psql_engine, only=["table1", "table2"])
remove_defaults_from_tables(Base.metadata)
```